# MySQL Attempting to remove a sub string from being counted with a count for a table

Tags: mysql-workbench, where-clause

```
SELECT session_uid, store_fk, COUNT(t.pk)

FROM report.scene_visit_summary svs

LEFT JOIN static.template t
ON svs.template_fk = t.pk

WHERE session_uid in ( '*******' , '********' , '*******') AND 
t.name NOT IN ('Main')


GROUP BY svs.store_fk
```

I basically want to remove any template with the word 'Main' in it from being counted by the query. Basically this part of the coding in

```
AND t.name NOT IN ('Main')
```

This currently does not exclude templates with the word Main in it such as 'Main Fridge' for example which is still counted in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could do just a NOT LIKE, i dont know your SQL Schema, but most probably it will work for you.

```
SELECT session_uid, store_fk, COUNT(t.pk)

FROM report.scene_visit_summary svs

LEFT JOIN static.template t
ON svs.template_fk = t.pk

WHERE session_uid in ( '*******' , '********' , '*******') AND 
t.name NOT LIKE '%Main%'


GROUP BY svs.store_fk
```

Answer (score 0):

> I basically want to remove any template with the word 'Main' in it
>   from being counted by the query.

**THE SOLUTION IS SO SIMPLER THEN YOUR QUERY**

```
SELECT session_uid, store_fk, COUNT(t.pk)

FROM report.scene_visit_summary svs

LEFT JOIN static.template t
ON svs.template_fk = t.pk

WHERE session_uid in ( '*******' , '********' , '*******') AND 
t.name NOT LIKE ('%Main%')


GROUP BY svs.store_fk
```

There is a like operator that you can use, try with like and let me know if it works .